# Magento 1.8.1 and percona server 5.6

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql

Currently i'm running magento version 1.8.1 with mysql 5.5
I'm about to upgrade the database to percona server

I was wondering whether its safe to upgrade to percona server 5.6?
Because there are some articles around the web that talks about issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are safe to upgrade to Percona 5.6.

> Always test your upgrade before doing this in production.